# Concatenation Statement

Tags: sql-server

I am using a concatenation statement to return Last Name, First Name Middle initial with a period (.). Ex: “Brown, John R.”.  The statement is as follows:

```
IF([Middle Name]  IS NULL ) 
THEN (trim([Last Name])+', '+trim([First Name]))
ELSE (trim([Last Name])+', '+trim([First Name])+' '+substring(nullif([Middle Name],' '),1,1)+'.'))
```

However, the statement is randomly omitting several of the names in the returned result. If I do not use the "nullif" option, it still returns periods where there is no middle initial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: which names are getting omitted? the ones with middle name or ones without?

Comment: Is [Middle Name] `NULL`, or is [Middle Name] just an empty string?

Comment: what you do after `THEN` does not make sense, also it looks like a VB syntax rather than an IF statement in SQL

Answer (score 0):

How about replace the whole thing with:

```
SELECT trim([Last Name])+', '+trim([First Name]) + Isnull(' ' + LEFT([Middle NAME],1) + '.','') AS FullName
```

Are all the first and last names filled in (NOT Null)?